# Spawn prefab randomly over polygon collider 2d in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, 2d-games, collider, prefab

I have attached pollygon collider 2d on this gameObject.

[image]

This gameObject is parent of another gameObject (just small circle).

**I want that small circle to randomly spawn somwhere on pollygon collider.**

I tried something like this:

```
private void GetBounds()
{
    polygonCollider = transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
    bounds = polygonCollider.bounds;
    
}

public void TargetSetPosition()
{
    x = Random.Range(bounds.min.x, bounds.max.x);
    y = Random.Range(bounds.min.y, bounds.max.y);

    transform.localPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
}
private void Start()
{
    GetBounds();
    TargetSetPosition();
}
```

**This script is attached to that small circle. In 80% cases is good result but sometimes it get weird something like this:**

[image]

Can someone help me please, becouse i tried almost everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bounds = polygonCollider.bounds` is getting the bounds of the [bounding box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box). So in your second pic, the ball is inside the bounds.

To make it be inside the collider of your objects, you need to try something else, like [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/40996/check-if-position-is-inside-a-collider.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I looked at the link and I'm not able to do it based on that answer. I don't understand it much. I understand that the ball is in bounds and all this stuff, but I don't understand how to fix it. Sorry I am pretty new in Unity.

Comment: Glad that helped. With raycasting you can check if a determined point is inside your shape. [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/163864/test-if-point-is-in-collider.html?_ga=2.149669686.188731061.1614424911-246435326.1564921029) there is another good resource. Once you get to understand why your current approach is not working, you can move on to research another approach that might work

Comment: That's a bad solution it's just trial and error until it works.